# Property map does not exist on type Observable<ArrayBuffer>

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-httpclient, angular6

I was trying to update from Angular v4 to Angular v6.
I was replacing `Http` and `HttpModule` to `HttpClient` and `HttpClientModule`.
So I imported `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http` in a service and was trying to get results from DBpedia's API.Earlier I was using `Http` from `@angular/http` and my following code was working fine

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Jsonp, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams} from "@angular/http";
import {Store} from "@ngrx/store";
import * as fromRoot from '../reducers';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class KnowledgeapiService {

  server = 'http://lookup.dbpedia.org';
  searchURL = this.server + '/api/search/KeywordSearch?';
  homepage = 'https://susper.com';
  logo = '../images/susper.svg';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private jsonp: Jsonp,
    private store: Store<fromRoot.State>
  ) {}

  public getsearchresults(searchquery){
    let params = new URLSearchParams();

    params.set('QueryString', searchquery);

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });
    let options:any = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, search: params });

    return this.http
      .get(this.searchURL, options).map(res =>

        res.json()

      ).catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError (error: any) {
    // In some advance version we can include a remote logging of errors
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // Right now we are logging to console itself
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

but now when I migrated from `Http` dependency to `HttpClient`, In function `getsearchresults(searchquery)` whenever I use `map` function map data to json,it gives an error that `map` function does not exist on type `Observable<ArrayBuffer>` .Further removing `map` function gives same message for `catch` function. I followed this link https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15548 but solution provided in it does not work for me.Where I am Wrong? Should I remove both `map` and `catch` function in `getsearchresults(searchquery)`.

Comment: provide the query string  and see if this works for you [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-els9mw)

Comment: Please elaborate!!

Comment: I would for sure prior to it just give me a confirmation whether the provided stackblitz works or not if you pass the correct query param

Comment: Yeah,It is generating the link but due to Mixed Content as response from DBpedia is HTTP the result is not shown on console.

Comment: could you fork  and provide me the stackblitz with your edits

Comment: This code won't work on stackblitz as it is using https, but the response from DBpedia is in http.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170962/discussion-between-praveen-ojha-and-vikas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are facing issues with `types`. The above typescript code is not consistent. For example no type is defined for `getsearchresults()` function. No type is defined in `this.http.get<NoTypeDefinedHere>`

Further `httpClient` gives json response by default.And `let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });` might not be needed here.

Check if you are using `http` module or `httpClient` module in import.

Check if you have imported `rxjs/add/operator/map` correctly

Comment: Thanks for your answer, As I have told earlier I was using `Http` module but now I have switched to `HttpClient` module. I have also imported `rxjs/add/operator/map` . Earlier everything was working correctly with the above code. Also I think `headers` will not cause any trouble here. I have removed `map` function now but now it gives same error message for `catch` function. Can you please suggest any solution.

Comment: can you update you question to share the import statements ?

Comment: I have edited my code to include imports. Please have a look.

Comment: Root cause is your Headers. import HttpHeaders from @angular/common/http instead of @angular/http. Response type will be json than instead of arrayBuffer. Please refer https://angular.io/guide/http. for further understanding.